# Default value not highlighted in material select control in angular application

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have implemented a material mat-select dropdown in my angular reactive application and want to highlight the default item. I am able to display a checkmark to show the default item using css but not able to highlight it as selected value (The blue bar). I am assigning the isDefault value to true but it doesn't seem to work. The default item has a property isDefault with boolean value = true

```
   <mat-form-field [floatLabel]="'never'">
      <mat-select placeholder="select"  formControlName="name"  >
        <mat-option value="">-- Select an option --</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of nameOptions$ |async" [ngClass]="{'checkmark':item.isDefault==true}" [value]="item.isDefault">
          {{item.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using reactive forms, so you need to set the default value to the formcontrol itself, that is how angular know which value to set as default. So either do that when you are building the form, if you know which value should be set as default.

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  name: ['default value here']
});
```

or if you get the value at a later point and need to assign it, you can call `setValue`:

```
this.myForm.get('name').setValue('default value here');
```

If you don't know which item in advance, you probably you would want to `tap` into your observable array, `find` the one that should be selected and use `setValue`

Something like this, "pseudoish"...

```
nameOptions$ = this.whateverService.getNameOptions().pipe(
  tap((values: MyNameOptionsModel[]) => {
     const found = values.find((value: MyNameOptionsModel) => value.isDefault);
     this.myForm.get('name').setValue(found?.isDefault)
  })
)
```

I don't know if you really want this though, meaning to use the boolean value, I would rather save the actual item name instead, because now your form will just be `{name: true}` which is not helpful, so probably you would want to use an id (if exists) or then the actual name to assign to the formcontrol.

Comment: The object that gets bound to the name control is like {
    "name": "Steven",
    "isDefault": true
},
{
    "name": "Tom",
    "isDefault": false
}

Comment: I tried this   public form = this.fb.group({
    name: [ { firstName: 'Steven', isDefault: true }],
  })

Comment: That does not work :(

Comment: well you are trying to set an object as the formcontrol value, either pass just one of the properties or make a nested formgroup.

Comment: public form = this.fb.group({
    name: [ 'isDefault: true' ]
  })
AND
  public form = this.fb.group({
    name: [ 'true' ]
  })

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do there, just that is not valid code for reactive forms. This is what I would do, using name property: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yfw35y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts i.e just swapping the isDefault to using name instead If you want more data stored than just the name, use a nested formgroup instead of just one formcontrol.